# How to click link with same names in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am using selenium web driver with java. i want to click on the link with name Downloads.
Actually there are four links with the same name. when i inspect the element i get

```
<a href="http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/selenium-java-2.41.0.zip"></a>
```

i am trying to click the link with the following

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@ href='//http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/selenium-java-2.41.0.zip']")).click();
```

In the following link i am trying to click on the first Download link.
[Selenium Download](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/)

Click is not working. Can any body please tell me how can i click this specific link ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your xpath is correct except 2 things:

1. whitespace between @ and href;
2. 2 slashes before http.

Correct this and it will work.

Also I wouldn't recommend use such xpaths. In case href value changed your xpath will not be working.

So to avoid this you can use xpath like:

`//tbody//td[text()='Java']/following-sibling::td/a[text()='Download']`

It will click download link for Java even if href value was changed (eg. to 2.42).

Answer (score 1):

Richard's answer is correct, but this xpath is easier to read:

```
//td[(text()='Java')]/following-sibling::td/a[text() = 'Download']
```

Answer (score 0):

This xpath will locate the Download link for Java:

```
//td[(text()='Java')]/following-sibling::td[3]/a
```

Answer (score 0):

Give small space between 'a' tag,

```
<a href="http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/selenium-java-2.41.0.zip"> </a>
```

takeout //(double forward slash) from before http words.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/selenium-java-2.41.0.zip']")).click();
```

if we using

```
//td[(text()='Java')]/following-sibling::td/a[text() = 'Download']
```

this code reflect only webdrive(testing) . so,i put small modification on 'Fani Khokhar' code.

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/',
            success: function(data) {
                var html = $.parseHTML(data);
                var main_content = $(html).find('#mainContent table:eq(0)');
                var row_count = main_content.find("tbody").find("tr");
                for (var i = 0; i < row_count.length; i++) {
                    var MyIndexValue = $(main_content.find("tbody").find("tr:eq(" + i + " )")).find("td:eq(0)").html();
                    if (MyIndexValue == "Java") {
                        var href_value = main_content.find("tbody").find("tr:eq(0)").find("td:eq(3)").html();
                        var current_version_link = $(href_value).attr('href');
                        $("#here_getback_latest_version").html("<a href=" + current_version_link + "/> </a>");
                    } else {
                        console.log(MyIndexValue + " not required.");
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
```

follow by,

```
<div id="here_getback_latest_version"></div>
```

If we modified in source code,even-though changes happen in latest version also its automatically download.

Comment: @FaniKhokhar I would recommend strongly against that answer.  It will break the next time the version of Selenium changes.

Comment: @Richard i added small modification.

Answer (score 0):

Alright.. There are so many ways we can identify the elements using xpath.

In addition to what others suggested, I just wanted to mention below method of identifying a specific element. It comes handy if you know the order of your element's occurrence in the web page.

```
(//a[text()='Download'])[2]
```

you may also refer few links like below for reference.

http://www.quackit.com/xml/tutorial/xpath_string_functions.cfm
http://news.rapgenius.com/Mat-brown-xpath-is-actually-pretty-useful-once-it-stops-being-confusing-annotated#note-2363798